Page scrolling when using fitBounds() to change map extent in Leaflet
I am using the Leaflet fitBounds() function to reset the extent to the original zoom level.  However, the map itself is contained in a DIV that is not at the top of the page.  When fitBounds() executes, the page is scrolled back to the top and the user has to scroll down to the map.
How can I prevent the page from scrolling?
Here is the code to define the "Full Extent" button:
L.Control.Extent = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function (map) {
        let container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-custom leaflet-bar leaflet-control');
        
        container.innerHTML = '<a class="leaflet-bar-part leaflet-bar-part-single" href="#" title="Expand to Full Extent" style="outline: medium none;"><span class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></span></a>';
        
        container.onclick = function() {
            map.fitBounds(locations.getBounds());
        }
        
        return container;
    }
});

L.control.extent = function(options) {
    return new L.Control.Extent(options);
}

L.control.extent({position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);


Problem is not in map.fitBounds call. Even if you leave this call out, clicking on control will have the same effect. I couldn't find a way to prevent this, so some hacking is required to remedy the problem.
Idea is to catch document scroll event and store scroll top position in global variable scrollTop. When control is clicked, save current scrollTop value to savedScrollTop. When as a consequence of control click document is scrolled to top, check in scroll processing function if scroll top was saved. If yes, set document scroll top to save position.
Here is how relevant part of the code could look like then (tested):
var scrollTop = 0;
var savedScrollTop = 0;

document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  scrollTop = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  if ((scrollTop == 0) && (savedScrollTop != 0)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollTop = savedScrollTop;
      savedScrollTop = 0;
      document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    }, 0);
  }
});
      
L.Control.Extent = L.Control.extend({
  onAdd: function (map) {
    let container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-custom leaflet-bar leaflet-control');         
    container.innerHTML = '<a class="leaflet-bar-part leaflet-bar-part-single" href="#" title="Expand to Full Extent" style="outline: medium none;"><span class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></span></a>';       
    container.onclick = function() {
      savedScrollTop = scrollTop;
      map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
    }       
    return container;
  }
});

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/fq4hg96p/
